# Что делает следующий фрагмент кода .gitlab-ci.yml файла?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Подскажите, что делает следующий фрагмент кода `.gitlab-ci.yml` файла:

```
except:
    - tags
artifacts:
    untracked: true
    expire_in: 1 day
```

Из документации по gitlab-ci, не совсем понял:

except - When a Git reference of a pipeline is a tag.

untracked: true  - подтягивать не отслеживаемые Git артефакты

expire_in: 1 day - хранить на сервере артефакты один день

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> except: tags

Gitlab CI запускается при получении новых изменений из локальных репозиториев. Чтобы инструкции из файла `.gitlab-ci.yml` не запускались на каждое такое изменение, есть возможность накладывать ограничения. В данном случае указывается, что запуск не происходит если на сервер отправляются только теги. То есть для следующих команд pipeline не запуститься, но изменения сервер получит.

```
git tag v0.0.1
git push --tags
```

> untracked: true

Указывает Gitlab Runner рассматривать как артефакты файлы, которые появляются после клонирования репозитория и выполнения `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Эти файлы не будут являются частью репозитория, то есть с точки зрения Git не отслеживаются.

> expire_in: 1 day

Если артефакты не удалять, то они будут копиться довольно быстро. Чтобы это не происходило Gitlab можно задать время хранения артефактов, по истечения этого времени артефакты будут удалены автоматически. Информация о ходе выполнения pipeline сохранится.